# How are videos on Youtube and such sites loaded and how is progress saved?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, scorm, lms, xapi

I hope you are doing well!

I am working on an eLearning website and came across the topic of the video loading. Since videos are of various sizes, it would be impossible to make the user wait for the entire download of the video for them to start watching, so it must be taken as a stream where the video keeps loading content as the user watches (similar to YouTube I guess). However, I am failing to find how this works? I've been recommended the use of SCORM and xAPI to help with this but I am only finding help on how to upload SCORM files or how to write xAPI code and not how to set them up in our website.

How can we make our videos download as the User watches? Are SCORM and xAPI actually what we should be looking for?

For context, we will be using React JS for our Frontend and will be saving the videos on a server.

I would greatly appreciate any advice you have and thank you for your time!

We tried using xAPI and SCORM however we aren't understanding how they might help

Answer (score 0):

SCORM and xAPI by themselves are not going to assist you with this in general. To stream video via an eLearning course you will need to use a video player (such as the HTML5 video player or video.js) that understands streaming video protocols and to encode the video files in a format supported by that player. I would suggest reading about HLS for instance, though I didn't read the entire page, this is a good place to start: https://www.dacast.com/blog/hls-streaming-protocol/

A traditional eLearning course, such as you would have with SCORM, is going to provide a reasonable way to wrap the playing of video such that it can be launched for a learner via an LMS and may capture data such as completion. xAPI is probably suggested because it provides a more robust way of enabling the capture of interaction data such as when the learner plays, pauses, or seeks in a video. My preferred approach for doing this is to leverage cmi5, and there is an example of xAPI video profile usage within a cmi5 course in the Project CATAPULT sample content, see https://github.com/adlnet/CATAPULT/tree/main/course_examples. It could be adapted to leverage something like HLS and get streaming capability. Confirm with your LMS of choice ahead of time whether it supports cmi5 as adoption is still lower than for SCORM.

SCORM Cloud (a bit of a misnomer, https://cloud.scorm.com/) provides builtin video handling via the cmi5 mechanism and will soon support video streaming beyond just from YouTube without the need to author a course separately.